# linking a ".ma" domain name with ovh vps

Tags: dns, vps

Hello I'm having trouble setting up dns to link this domain 1000mabrouk.ma with an ovh vps

The vps is running on centos 6.4 with cpanel

I'have bind installed on the vps

Here is the /var/named/1000mabrouk.ma.db

```
; cPanel first:11.42.1.16 (update_time):1402758901 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:vps71042.ovh.net latest:11.42.1.18
; Zone file for 1000mabrouk.ma
$TTL 14400
1000mabrouk.ma. 86400   IN      SOA     dns108.ovh.net. yerratbi.gmail.com.     (
                                                2014060404 ;Serial Number
                                                86400 ;refresh
                                                7200 ;retry
                                                3600000 ;expire
                                                86400 ;minimum
        )
1000mabrouk.ma. 86400   IN      NS      ns108.ovh.net.
1000mabrouk.ma. 86400   IN      NS      dns108.ovh.net.
1000mabrouk.ma. 14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
1000mabrouk.ma. 14400   IN      MX      0       1000mabrouk.ma.
mail    14400   IN      CNAME   1000mabrouk.ma.
www     14400   IN      CNAME   1000mabrouk.ma.
ftp     14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
cpanel  14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
webdisk 14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
whm     14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
webmail 14400   IN      A       37.187.182.93
default._domainkey      14400   IN      TXT     "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC0jdlzlKYOhHuH2RTsLlKjurhgzw+R/pVfX807D2rKzSEOFtKsemFAAgRivo42Z6+4Kl1aryIUL1CYjgt4KksQwr+ZAySVTAnR/dWfcrRTFivqEvfvYHM1gKA3RtvPhTJC6fgUjeBotpdDijoP9juK5mQHodPs+oiem+/5Ba5WxQIDAQAB;"
```

My experience with dns and bind is little to none please i need your help to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

name servers srv3-1000mabrouk.ma and its alias srv4-1000mabrouk.ma refuse requests, As your zone file states different nameserver, I suppose you didn't delegate authority over zone to those nameservers

Comment: I really didn't understand what you said

Comment: What I told you is the or one problem with that domain. I am sorry if you don't understand, you may want to read a bit about domain management, or delegate fixing it to somebody who does understand.

Comment: Can you put me on the right track to fix this, i'm sorry for my ignorance, this is way out of my zone of expertise and there is no way i can delegate this to someone else

Comment: is 100mabrouk.ma pointing to these nameservers (srv3-1000mabrouk.ma and srv4-1000mabrouk.ma) is there a way to get the who is of this domaine and sorry again for my dumb questions

Comment: tools exist to query specific nameservers and trace the chain of delegation. you may want to look at dig or drill as examples for such tools, which allow you to answer those questions yourself, if invoked appropriately.